# peaks and troughs in MATLAB (but with corresponding definition of a peak and trough)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, while-loop

I want to look for peaks and troughs in a given vector of data, with the following definition.

A "peak" is a local maximum at least x% higher than the preceding trough, and a "trough" is a local minimum at least x% lower than the preceding peak. x here is referred to as a cutoff. In the paper I am writing, the cutoff is referred to as the standard deviation of the data.

I thought of writing a function that enables me to find a peak and a trough. The function that  I wrote was this. I will call this from the main data.

```
function [vectpeak,vecttrough]=peaktrough(cutoff,x,lastobs,t)

% This function gives you two outputs: a vector of ones and zeros that locate PEAKS and     
% a vector of ones and zeros that locate TROUGHS. 
% To be able to get a vector of peaks and troughs, we have to give 
% four inputs.
% CUTOFF: This is what Chang and Osler [1999] use to identify if a data
% point is a peak or a trough. A PEAK is defined as "a local maximum that is
% x percent higher than the preceding trough." (Chang and Osler, 1999) 
% and a TROUGH is defined as "a local minimum that is x percent lower 
% than the preceding peak." This is a scalar.
% VECTOR: This is the vector of data that will be used for the purposes of
% the identification.
% LASTOBS: This is the last observation of the data.
% t: This specifies the time.

% Pre-allocations.
vectpeak=zeros(lastobs,1); % This is the vector of peaks.
vecttrough=zeros(lastobs,1); % This is the vector of troughs.

% Computing for the troughid's and peakid's.
temptroughid=troughid(cutoff,x,lastobs,t);
temppeakid=peakid(cutoff,x,lastobs,t);

 % Determining whether a function is a peak or a trough.
 while t<lastobs
    t=t+1;
    if x(t)>=temptroughid(t);
        vecttrough(t)=1;
        vectpeak(t)=0;
        maximum=x(t);
    elseif x(t)<=temppeakid(t);
            vecttrough(t)=0;
            vectpeak(t)=1;
            minimum=x(t);
    else
            vecttrough(t)=0;
            vectpeak(t)=0;
    end
end

function findtrough=troughid(cutoff,y,lastobs,t)
% This function computes for the TROUGHID which will be used in
% determining whether we have a trough or a peak.

% Initializations. 
findtrough=zeros(lastobs,1);
tempmin=zeros(lastobs,1);
minimum=y(1);

% This is how the function works.
while t<lastobs;
    t=t+1;
    if y(t)<minimum;
       tempmin(t)=y(t);
       minimum=y(t);
    else tempmin(t)=minimum;
    end
    findtrough(t)=tempmin(t)*(1+cutoff);
end
end

function findpeak=peakid(cutoff,y,lastobs,t)
% This function computes for the PEAKID which will be used in
% determining whether we have a peak.

% Initializations.
findpeak=zeros(lastobs,1);
tempmax=zeros(lastobs,1);
maximum=y(1);

% This is how the function works.
while t<lastobs;
     t=t+1;
     if y(t)>maximum;
       tempmax(t)=y(t);
       maximum=y(t);
    else tempmax(t)=maximum;
    end
    findpeak(t)=tempmax(t)*(1-cutoff);
end
end
end
```

The problem that I am getting is that I am getting weird results. For instance, I get a vector where all are peaks, and none are troughs, which does not make sense, since if I use the `findpeaks` command of MATLAB, I am able to identify peaks and troughs, and they are not successive.

Is there a way where I could tweak my code, or if not, to use findpeaks or its algorithm to find the peaks and troughs based on my definition?

Comment: I don't exactly know what `findtrough(t)=tempmin(t)*(cutoff);` is supposed to do, but I am pretty certain it is not doing what you want.  It seems like you want to use `(1 + cutoff)`as the factor.  It doesn't make sense to me to use the same factor in the trough and the peak, anyway.

Comment: @dustincarr Yeah, you're right, I just saw that it was a mistake. Then again, even with those corrections, I still don't get what I want.

Comment: It is still not quite right.  You actually probably want the factor to be 1/cutoff instead of 1+cutoff.  That was my mistake for suggesting 1+cutoff.  Even still, there is still something wrong with your comparisons.  I'll propose a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, your code does not actually identify peaks or troughs.  I think you should probably start with findpeaks to get a list of candidate peaks and troughs.  Then, step through this list to test if each one satisfies the condition.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the second thing that I thought of. :) What I am unsure of, is on how to implement the test for being a peak or a trough. One idea that I had was to compute for the percentage change between the candidate peaks and troughs, but there might be problems.

Comment: Another idea was to create 2 vectors; the first contains indicators for peaks, and the second, an indicator for troughs. Afterwards, I write a loop for the data that I have where I check the ratio, and then implement the algorithm for detecting for candidate peaks and troughs. Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem is that you can't really make your indicator unless you know where the peaks or troughs are.

Comment: Thanks. I tried writing the algorithm again, this time around, using your suggestion, but it seems that there again is a mistake. I'll post it as an addendum to my previous post.